# Suppose $f$ is twice differentiable function such that ...

Tags: definite-integrals

I am stuck with the following problem :

[image]

I  did  [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) which gives the result $\,\,f'(1)$.

Can someone explain? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you think of a reason that $f\,'(1)=f\,'(0)$?

Comment: Yes ,I can. It comes from the fact that $\,\,f(x+1)=f(x) \implies f'(x+1)=f'(x).$ But how can I use this result to have a conclusion?

Comment: @learner Because $f'(0)$ is one of the options. You know that the answer is $f'(1)$, and you know that $f'(1) = f'(0)$, thus that would be the correct alternative.

Comment: @Arthur thanks a lot..Got it...